# SAS: How to perform a maximum likelihoood estimation use PROC NLMIXED?

Tags: sas

All I am trying to do is to perform a maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters of a one-side truncated normal. I think I have specified the likelihood properly but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: Invalid Operation. ERROR: Termination due to Floating Point
>   Exception

I don’t think there is anything wrong with my code.

```
data ln;
    input dor 8.;
    qt=quantile("normal", dor, 0, 1);   
    datalines;
0.10
0.20
0.15
0.22
0.15
0.10
0.08
0.09
0.12
;
run;

/* obtain number accounts */
%let dsn = ln;
%let dsnid = %sysfunc(open(&dsn));
%let nobs=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsnid,nlobs));
%let rc  =%sysfunc(close(&dsnid));

proc sql noprint;
    select count(*), mean(qt), std(qt) into :nobs, :mean, :std
    from ln;
quit;

%put &nobs.;
%put &mean.;
%put &std.;

proc nlmixed data=LN;
parms mu &mean. sigma &std.;                 * initial values of parameters;
bounds 0 < sigma;                   * bounds on parameters;
LL = logpdf("normal", qt, mu, sigma) - &nobs.*logcdf("normal",qt, mu, sigma);
model qt ~ general(LL);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I only fails to run in SAS Enterprise Guide (EG). It ran fine on Base SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider your version of SAS.

Following documentation here :
http://support.sas.com/kb/46/318.html

> This error occurs when the client system is running the 32-bit version
>   of SAS because the 32-bit version of SAS cannot open a table that
>   contains more than 2,147,483,647 observations. This number is the
>   largest value that can be stored in a 32-bit variable, and it is
>   sometimes referred to as 2G-1, where 2G-1 means 2^31-1.

It seems possible to fix it but I kindly suggest you to continue to run the code on SAS Base if it's running well and if you don't want to waste time in system configuration.

Regards,